An Asian film about a thug who discovers he has super powers
I believe this was on standard cable many years ago. Maybe the Syfy channel. I think it was dubbed.
It starts with this thug who is part of a gang terrorizing an apartment building. At some point, the thug has a change of heart and tries to protect the people of this neighborhood. He is savagely beated by his now former boss and the other thugs. The apartment dwellers take his broken body in and wrap him entirely in bandages.
The boss returns with the thugs and the neighborhood tries to stand up to him, but fails. At this point, the thug emerges from the bandages, completely healed and now is some sort of Bruce Lee-style martial arts master. He and the boss fight, with him injuring the boss. The boss then takes on some toad-like form, complete with a frog goiter and superhuman jumping skills. They continue fighting and the boss knocks the former thug high into the sky, where he meets Buddha. He then spins around and begins to "slap". The boss makes this all-fours leap out of the way, and the imprint of a giant hand is left on the ground where he had been.
Toads are a common theme in Asian movies so it's been hard to find.

Kung Fu Hustle by Stephen Chow

In 1940s Shanghai, petty crooks Sing and Bone aspire to join the notorious Axe Gang, led by the cold-blooded killer, Brother Sum. The pair visit a rundown slum known as Pigsty Alley to extort the residents by pretending to be Axe members. Sing's actions eventually attract attention of the real gang, who confront the villagers. Gang reinforcements arrive but they are all quickly dealt with by three of the slum's tenants: Coolie, Tailor, and Donut, who are actually kung fu masters. However, fearing the Axe Gang's retaliation, the slum's Landlady evicts the trio.

....

Brother Sum is initially skeptical of the Beast due to his flippant attitude and sloppy appearance, but quickly changes his mind when the Beast stops a bullet midair. The Beast meets the Landlady and Landlord at the casino next door, engaging them in a fierce fight that ends in a stalemate. Sing, realizing the error of his ways, attacks the Beast, who angrily retaliates. The Landlady and Landlord grab the unconscious Sing and flee. The Beast eliminates Brother Sum and takes over as leader of the Axes.
The Landlady and Landlord treat Sing at Pigsty Alley and are surprised by his quick recovery. The Landlady deduces Sing is, in fact, a natural-born kung fu genius. With his newfound powers, Sing effortlessly dispatches the Axes before fighting the Beast. Sing embraces the Buddha and uses the Buddhist Palm to neutralize the Beast, who concedes defeat.

The Beast indeed uses a Toad Stance to attack Sing before he uses the Buddhist Palm in his final attack.
Trailer



Also the answer to Film, pre 1993, Kung Fu elements and teleportation

Yeah, that was it. I found the clip of the section I watched. Thanks!
